# Rollback a question during review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060635/slider-function-delay) popup in my first-post queue. It seems the user asked a question, got the answer he/she was looking for, then edited their question to be "........................."

What should be done in this case? It can't be deleted since it has an answer with upvotes. My initial thought was to have it rolled back to the previous edit. I don't seem to have that option in my review though. Copy-pasting the previous edit doesn't feel right, but would it be the right course of action?

**Update:**

I've accepted Jashaszun's answer for now as no other solutions were posted. As Jashaszun points out, the only two options seem to be either edit the question outside of the review, or copy-paste a previous version and save it as an edit within the review. To me, the former feels like the better solution of the two and is what I will do if I see this again.

If another solution is presented, I will update this question.

Comment: FWIW, he's vandalised his other post aswell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070778/image-squashed-as-browser-width-decreases.

Comment: I always found it stupid that you cannot delete your own questions as soon as there are answers. There might be several reasons why you don't want to keep a particular question posted in your own name. At the very least, you should be able to turn your questions into anonymous community wikis. It is ridiculous that you have to flag for moderator attention for things like this. Until SO fixes this, I actually feel that vandalizing your own posts is the correct thing to do, as a protest against the poor site design decisions.

Comment: I suppose you're free to look for help on other sites where you can do it anonymously.

Comment: @Lundin - [The first thing we learn about SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) - "[...] With your help, we're working together to **build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming**."

Comment: @Lundin: If you disagree for how the site is being run in regards to keeping questions (that is, we are not your personal question answerer machine where you can keep the questions in secret), the **don't post anything here**.

Comment: I would say for such vandalisms, people should have their precious reps vandalized too. How about cutting them in half? Of course for this particular case...

Comment: @Lundin - I don't think being able to completely remove your question once you have accepted an answer or a solution has been provided for you should be an option. This is a community and lots of people may have the same problem, thus is this action was performed, someone may not any reference if stuck themselves.

Comment: There are many reasons why you might want to delete your question. You realized that you made serious, incorrect statements. You realized that the problem is not related to something in the question and you already solved it. You realized that the question is inappropriate for the site for some reason. And so on. These are all valid reasons to delete the post.

Comment: As for the community aspect, I already proposed that you should be able to convert your question into a community wiki. There exists no reason why this shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @PlasmaHH If we aren't allowed to disagree with anything, then we can close Meta right away.

Comment: @Lundin: You can write all of your disagreement on meta as  much as you want, as long as until the community changes, you play well with the community rules. Vandalizing your questions to "protest against the poor site design decisions" is at best childish. You disagree? fine. But don't destroy the value the community built, and stick to the rules, or try to get the rules changed. If you fail to do so, and don't like the place, go away. Just like in real world, you may not like some laws, but you shouldn't complain for getting arrested when you break them.

Comment: @ivarni: You can always do it anonymously here too, by creating a new account for each equestion...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Playing by the rules would involve flagging for moderator attention as soon as you want a question removed. I would imagine that this happens many times per day. The moderator may or may not agree with you, but you'd create a massive work-load for them. Is this what you would recommend then? There are many other cases where you can't play by the rules, because the rules are stupid. -->

Comment: Take For example the dysfunctional edit review queue, where many people resort to all kinds of tricks to prevent robo reviewers from approving crap. That's another form of protest and the intent is to make the site better. Same goes for closing very basic questions as "unclear what you are asking", That's another protest against the site, the users don't want those crap questions so they close them, even though there is no site policies against asking too basic questions.

Comment: @Lundin: If you think the rules are stupid, raise a meta question and get community approval for it being stupid and a change request. If that gets denied, the majority of the community does not think it is stupid. And yes, I think it is a good idea to raise a flag to get a question with an answer deleted, to have a second pair of eyes look onto it and if it has value for the community it should be kept. You can also always ask for disassociation from your account only. And yes, this is work for moderators, but since those are exceptions, invoking said exception handles is the way to go.

Comment: @Lundin `Same goes for closing very basic questions as "unclear what you are asking", That's another protest against the site, the users don't want those crap question so they close them, even though there is no site policies against asking too basic questions.` Except that we don't close basic questions as "unclear". We only close *unclear* questions as "unclear". Basic questions are not equivalent to unclear questions, and the community here knows that.

Comment: @Jashaszun You are citing the site policies as a response to my example of a case where people deliberately don't follow said policies? I'm glad you still have some illusions about the community, but questions that are too basic for some people's taste are closed everyday, with some random close reason picked as pretext.

Comment: @Jashaszun One such example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171472/programming-c-language-temperature-conversion). There are no problems with question itself, as far as SO policies are concerned, the OP even managed to pin-point the location of the error. But it is a very basic question, which seems to be the only reason why it has gotten two down votes and one close vote. The close vote was for "Off topic, questions asking for debug help must include the specific problem..." which the question does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just click on the question title (or middle-click or ctrl-click) to go to the question. Find the bad edit, and then roll it back from there.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I do that, then it won't count for the review. I think I've accidentally done that before, just to come back to the review and see I haven't completed it yet.

Comment: @j.f. Oh, that's what you mean. Well is it that important that you do that *one* review? If it is, then I guess that copy-pasting the previous edit would be the only thing to do.

Comment: No, it wouldn't matter (I didn't get credit for it anyway), but I came across it and didn't know what to do. I figured if I skipped it, someone else would come across it and possibly have the same question. I didn't know if there was a way to handle it or if there should be one in case there isn't.

Comment: If you are doing it for "credit" you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Like my previous comment mentioned, I'm not. I just didn't know what to do.